# Does reading data from SPView give better performance than reading from SPList?

Tags: wss-3.0, performance, spview

**I would like to understand if reading data from a SPView gives better response time than reading directly from a SPList.**

Basically I got this question as I have a **SPlist with almost 30 columns**, and I am **trying to read only 3 columns** in my code. Now I found out that in SP2013, it is possible to use SPQuery.ViewFieldsOnly property to ensure that data from selected columns is fetched. But my organization is currently **using WSS 3.0 (WSS3.0 does not have a SPQuery.ViewFieldsOnly property)**. So I am thinking to create a view to fetch data. My SPList contains many items and I need to prepare a report on a button click event in a SPWebPart. So as you can understand, **response time is important** to me. I want to save as much execution time as possible by fetching only required fields from my SPList.

I am looking at the following code sample using SPView:

```
SPListItemCollection coll = web.Lists["ListName"].GetItems(web.Lists["ListName"].Views["ViewName"]);
```

Using SPList:

```
SPListItemCollection coll = web.Lists["ListName"].GetItems(web.Lists["ListName"]);
```

**Will the SPView sample give a better response time assuming that I have many rows of data in the SPList? or is it the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, always query your list with CAML and assign view fields, simply cycling the listitemcollection will give you bad performance.

Calling a view means you're basically extracting the CAML from that view and using it to do a query. Meaning you'll have great performance. Recommended approach.

Comment: Ohk, now I understand how querying the view can result in a better response time. I wish I had known this before. Thanks a lot!